# How to convert the UNIX time stamp values into desired date and time formats and update the same into an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp

I've an associative array titled $eventDetails consisting details of events as follows :

```
//Output of print_r($eventDetails);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [event_id] => 503
                    [title] => AppCampusEvent1
                    [time_stamp] => 1451632930
                    [start_time] => 1451718000
                    [end_time] => 1451721600
                    [event_group_date] => 02 Jan, Saturday 2016
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [event_id] => 504
                    [title] => AppCampusEvent2
                    [time_stamp] => 1451633275
                    [start_time] => 1451718000
                    [end_time] => 1451721600
                    [event_group_date] => 02 Jan, Saturday 2016
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [event_id] => 501
                    [title] => DemoEvent5
                    [time_stamp] => 1451567866
                    [start_time] => 1452103200
                    [end_time] => 1452193200
                    [event_group_date] => 07 Jan, Thursday 2016
                )

        )
)
```

I want to convert the UNIX time stamp values that are present into keys `[start_time]` and `[end_time]` of above array to user readable format.
These converted values should be added to the new keys of the array `$eventDetails` and final array should look like below :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [event_id] => 503
                    [title] => AppCampusEvent1
                    [time_stamp] => 1451632930
                    [start_time] => 1451718000
                    [end_time] => 1451721600
                    [event_group_date] => Saturday, January 2
                    [event_start_time] => 02:00 PM  
                    [event_end_time] => 03:00 PM    
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [event_id] => 504
                    [title] => AppCampusEvent2
                    [time_stamp] => 1451633275
                    [start_time] => 1451718000
                    [end_time] => 1451721600
                    [event_group_date] => 02 Jan, Saturday 2016
                    [event_start_time] => 02:00 PM
                    [event_end_time] => 03:00 PM        
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [event_id] => 501
                    [title] => DemoEvent5
                    [time_stamp] => 1451567866
                    [start_time] => 1452103200
                    [end_time] => 1452193200
                    [event_group_date] => 07 Jan, Thursday 2016
                    [event_start_time] => 01:00 AM
                    [event_end_time] => 02:00 AM            
                )

        )
)
```

The new keys `[event_start_time] and [event_end_time]` contains the equivalent values of keys `[start_time] and [end_time]` respectively(after conversion).

I checked the default timezone of a server by using following command :

```
<?php
  echo date_default_timezone_get();
?>
```

It given me the output :
**America/Los_Angeles**

So can somebody please help me out in my issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try following.

```
date_timestamp_set($date, 1171502725);
echo date_format($date, 'U = Y-m-d H:i:s');
```